# Get variable scope in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, variables, scope

I am using the new version of tensorflow (2.0.0 alpha) and I dont know why it  does not allow me to run:

```
tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_variable_scope'
```

I guess there is a new attribute with a different name? Thanks!

Comment: No, `variable_scope` and `get_variable` have been removed from TensorFlow 2.x (although you can still find them under [`tf.compat.v1`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1)). See the RFC [Variables in TensorFlow 2.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180817-variables-20.md).

Answer (score 1):

From comments

> No, `variable_scope` and `get_variable` have been removed from `TensorFlow 2.x` (although you can still find them under [tf.compat.v1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1)). In `TF 2.x` to returns the current variable scope you can use `tf.compat.v1.get_variable_scope` instead of `get_variable_scope`. For more details please refer [Migrate from TF1 to TF2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate). (paraphrased from jdehesa).